# Doubly linked list - segfault

Tags: c, memory-management, doubly-linked-list

I have a doubly linked list,

```
struct node
{
   int data;
   struct node *prev;
   struct node *next;
};
```

and a `deleteEnd` function I implemented,

```
bool deleteEnd(struct node **head, int* value) {
    if (*head == NULL) return false;
    struct node* end = *head;
    while (end->next != NULL) {
        end = end->next;
    }

    if (end == *head) *head = NULL;
    else end->prev->next = NULL;

    *value = end->data;
    free(end);

    return true;
}
```

that gives me a segmentation fault but I can't figure out why. At this point my list have 3 elements (`1<->2<->5`) and `5` should be deleted.

**list.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <stdbool.h>

/* doubly linked list structure */
struct node
{
   int data;
   struct node *prev;
   struct node *next;
};

struct node* create(int value);
bool insertAtBeginning(struct node **head, int value);
bool insertAtEnd(struct node **head, int value);
bool insertAfter(struct node **head, int value, int preVal);
bool deleteBeginning(struct node **head, int* value);
bool deleteEnd(struct node **head, int* value);
bool deleteSpecific(struct node **head, int value);
void display(struct node *head);
```

**list.c**

```
#include "list.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct node* create(int value) {
    struct node* n = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if (n == NULL) return NULL;
    n->data = value;
    n->prev = NULL;
    n->next = NULL;
    return n;
}
bool insertAtBeginning(struct node **head, int value) {
    struct node* old_head = *head;
    *head = create(value);
    if (*head == NULL) return false;
    (*head)->next = old_head;
    return true;
}
bool insertAtEnd(struct node **head, int value) {
    // Get last node
    struct node* last = *head;
    while (last->next != NULL) {
        last = last->next;
    }
    // Insert after
    last->next = create(value);
    if (last->next == NULL) return false;
    else return true;
}
bool insertAfter(struct node **head, int value, int preVal) {
    // Get previous
    struct node* prev = *head;
    while (prev->data != preVal && prev->next != NULL) {
        prev = prev->next;
    }
    // Not founnd ?
    if (prev->next == NULL && prev->data != preVal) return false;

    // Insert in between
    struct node* nxt = prev->next;
    struct node* insert = create(value);
    if (insert == NULL) return false;
    prev->next = insert;
    insert->next = nxt;
    return true;
}
bool deleteBeginning(struct node **head, int* value) {
    struct node* hd = *head;
    *value = hd->data;
    *head = (*head)->next;
    free(hd);
    return true;
}
bool deleteEnd(struct node **head, int* value) {
    if (*head == NULL) return false;
    struct node* end = *head;
    while (end->next != NULL) {
        end = end->next;
    }

    if (end == *head) *head = NULL;
    else end->prev->next = NULL;

    *value = end->data;
    free(end);

    return true;
}
bool deleteSpecific(struct node **head, int value) {
    // Find node
    struct node* n = *head;
    while (n->data != value && n->next != NULL) {
        n = n->next;
    }
    // Not found ?
    if (n->next == NULL && n->data != value) return false;

    // Deleting head ?
    if (n == *head) {
        *head = (*head)->next;
        free(n);
    }
    // Delete in between
    else {
        struct node* nxt = n->next;
        struct node* prev = n->prev;
        prev->next = nxt;
        free(n);
    }
    return true;
}
void display(struct node *head) {
    if (head == NULL) {
        printf("List is Empty!!!");
    }
    else {
        printf("\nList elements are:\n");
        do {
            printf("%d ", head->data);
            head = head->next;
        }
        while(head != NULL);
        printf("\n\n");
    }
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "list.h"

int main()
{
    int value, preVal, retVal;
    struct node *head = NULL;


    /* insert data */
    value = 2;
    printf("insert %d %s\n", value, insertAtBeginning(&head, value) ? "OK":"NOK");

    display(head);

    value = 5;
    printf("insert %d %s\n", value, insertAtEnd(&head, value) ? "OK":"NOK");

    display(head); // printf("blabla");

    value = 3;
    printf("insert %d %s\n", value, insertAtBeginning(&head, value) ? "OK":"NOK");

    display(head);

    value = 3;
    preVal = 0;
    printf("insert %d after %d %s\n", value, preVal, insertAfter(&head, value, preVal) ? "OK":"NOK");

    display(head);

    value = 1;
    preVal = 3;
    printf("insert %d after %d %s\n", value, preVal, insertAfter(&head, value, preVal) ? "OK":"NOK");

    display(head);

    /* delete data */
    retVal = deleteBeginning(&head, &value);
    printf("delete %d %s\n", value, retVal ? "OK": "NOK");
    display(head);
    retVal = deleteEnd(&head, &value);
    printf("delete %d %s\n", value, retVal ? "OK": "NOK");
    display(head);
    value = 3;
    retVal = deleteSpecific(&head, value);
    printf("delete %d %s\n", value, retVal ? "OK":"NOK");

    display(head);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which line within the function are you getting the segfault on?

Comment: Line 9, see the comment next to it.

Comment: What happens if there is only *one* node in the list? Are you setting up the links correctly when you add the nodes? You should be experienced enough to know how to create a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us. Maybe even to know how to use a debugger to step through your code (*all* of it) line by line to make sure it works as you expect it to?

Comment: The list is consistant afaik and has 3 nodes in my use case.

Comment: It's still a case you need to look into handling, which your current code (as shown) doesn't do.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude mind if I give you a Gist or something ? There is too much code here.

Comment: Can't you just make an example containing one function to add nodes to the list (the one you use), the `deleteEnd` function, and a very small `main` function that creates the list you show with three nodes, and then call the `deleteEnd` function? That's really all we need to see.

Comment: See my edit, that's all there is to it.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but your `insertAtBeginning` function have a big flaw in it: If the `create` function fails then you lose your whole list.

Comment: So have you tried compiling @Someprogrammerdude ?

Comment: Somethings wrong with your insertion code, when the crash happens the `prev` pointer in the last node is `NULL`. First of all try to minimize the code, try to remove (comment out) all insertion code, add one insertion at a time until you get the crash. Continue to remove code that's not needed to replicate the crash until you really have an MVCE. Then step through the code, ***all of the code***, line by line in a debugger to figure out why the last node gets a `NULL` previous pointer. I recommend you take some time to read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Hint: What do `insertAtEnd` *really* do? Try to explain it to your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: You said it right, I forgot to set the 'prev' pointer when inserting elements some place after the head hahaha. Thx hopefully this fixes it.

Comment: I'll accept your answer if you post a fixed code for the `insertAtEnd / insertAfter` functions, I've already fixed them btw.

Comment: linux? if so run the program under valgrind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case when end is equal to head this statement

```
end->prev->next = NULL; // <- segfault
```

results in undefined behavior because `end->prev` is equal to NULL;

I would define the function the following way

```
bool deleteEnd(struct node **head, int *value ) 
{
    bool success = *head != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        while ( ( *head )->next != NULL ) head = &( *head )->next;

        *value = ( *head )->data;

        struct node *last = *head;

        *head = NULL;

        free( last );
    }

    return success;
}
```

EDIT: After you showed additional code then it is already seen that at least this function

```
bool insertAtBeginning(struct node **head, int value) {
    struct node* old_head = *head;
    *head = create(value);
    if (*head == NULL) return false;
    (*head)->next = old_head;
    return true;
}
```

is wrong because it does not set the data member `prev` of `old_head`.

Or in this function

```
bool insertAtEnd(struct node **head, int value) {
    // Get last node
    struct node* last = *head;
    while (last->next != NULL) {
        last = last->next;
    }
    // Insert after
    last->next = create(value);
    if (last->next == NULL) return false;
    else return true;
}
```

there is no check whether *head is equal to NULL. And again the data member `prev` of the newly created node is not set appropriately.

This that is that the data member prev has the value NULL is the reason of incorrect work of the function `deleteEnd`.

You should revise all your functions.

Comment: Look at my edit I think it is clearer now (handling list has 1 element). Still the same problem. The only use case Im testing this fonction against btw is with a 3 nodes list.

Comment: @PinkTurtle It means that the problem is due to incorrect pushing elements into the list.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if end element has previous one. If it does not have, you can't write next element to that previous element.

You are missing if statement.

```
if (end->prev)
    end->prev->next = NULL; // <- segfault
```

Comment: The while loop loops as long as there is a 'next' element and moves to it.